# Override mongodb table name length limit

Tags: mongodb, nosql

When I pick a name, it says it should be less than 128 characters long. Is there somewhere where I can set mongodb to accept larger names? It would make life easier.

Comment: When you need collection names longer than 128 characters, it is a hint that you are not using collections the way it is intended. Generally you should rather use less collections than more.

Comment: BTW tables (from relational DB's in MongDB are called collections. Phillip is right, 128 chars is way too many for a collection name. Collections need to be easily reference-able and memorable.

Comment: Not if you're using mongodb as a cache of sorts.

Comment: @Philipp I agree with OP here, if the collection names are human readable but automatically generated, the arbitrary limit is a little low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't set anything to allow a namespace `<database>.<collection>` to be longer than 128 characters. I agree with Philipp here, that having this limit be a problem hints that you might not be using collections as intended.